# SwiftUI Optimization

Tags: swift, optimization, swiftui, grid

The following code takes quiet some time to compile, I was wondering if someone could optimize it. I am new to SwiftUI, so please don't judge me for that code

The following code generates a grid of VStacks(cells); I works, but it is slow and I don't want to have to wait that long and unoptimized code like this is generally not a good solution.

The code compiles fast if I use fixed numbers inside the ForEach loop, but with my current setup it is slow...

```
let paletteColumns = 4 // The amount of columns
let tmpCt = 18         // The amount of cells in total
VStack {
    ForEach (0..<(tmpCt / paletteColumns) + 1) {
        row in
        HStack {
            ForEach (0..<min(tmpCt-(row * paletteColumns), paletteColumns)) {
                col in
                VStack {
                    // CODE FOR EACH CELL
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: If you use iOS 14.0+ you can use `LazyVGrid` which might be faster

Comment: I am developing this app for macOS

Comment: The part that slows it down are the expressions inside the for loops

Comment: `LazyVGrid` is only faster at runtime, but if I'm not mistaken, Mario is asking about compile time.

Comment: Jep, but I fixed it for myself, see answer, thanks for your time though :)

Comment: Don't mix and match model and view code. I recommend to create an array (or whatever fits your model) with all the data ready to go and feed that into your view.

Comment: I have a data array, but this is for displaying it in a grid

Comment: Then maybe you can make a pre-calculated multidimensional array for your grid.

Comment: Nope, can't do that, but I fixed the problem, see answer and restructured it so that it uses Publishers and stuff, that's not in the answer though bc it is too complex to translate into this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i fixed my problem by putting the stuff of the second ForEach into a dedicated function.

Updated code:

```
func Whatever(row: Int) -> Int {
    return min(tmpCt-(row * paletteColumns), paletteColumns)
}

let paletteColumns = 4 // The amount of columns
let tmpCt = 18         // The amount of cells in total
VStack {
    ForEach (0..<(tmpCt / paletteColumns) + 1) {
        row in
        HStack {
            ForEach (0..<Whatever()) {
                col in
                VStack {
                    // CODE FOR EACH CELL
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

PS: Answer is not marked as answered since I have to wait for 2 days to accept my own answer